# Style not working for innerHTML in ionic "Angular"

Tags: innerhtml

When I am try passing html as innerHtml to my view styled component not work

```
<div [innerHTML]="Html Code"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To solve these issues using DomSanitizer to be able to render a CSS bypass.**

1. Generate a pipe :

   ionic g pipe safeHtml
2. Modfiey all code inside file pipe  by this:

   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
   import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

   @Pipe({
   name: 'safeHtml',
   })
   export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

   constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
   transform(html) {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
   }
   }
3. Add the pipe crated to app/app.module.ts  :

   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   MyApp,
   ...
   SafeHtmlPipe,
   ],
4. The last Point In your HTML file where you are using innerHTML add pipe :